# Qt addApplicationFont fails

Tags: c++, qt

I try to embed a font in resources.qrc file and load it in runtime with `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont` (Always returns -1)

Tried both on Ubuntu-gnome (which can fail according to docs), and on Windows Server 2008 (fails too).

Sample font: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ralsina/ubuntuone-windows-installer/no-credentials/view/head:/data/Ubuntu-R.ttf
(used in ubuntuone app, so should work in qt)

Sample loading code:

```
int result = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf");
```

Result is always -1

Comment: which is your build directory, try relative path from build directory, have you  tried that ?

Comment: Do you use Q_INIT_RESOURCE() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both [Akhil V Suku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929237/akhil-v-suku) and [user4419802](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4419802/user4419802) for pointing solution. It was related to resources, not fonts.

Font loaded successfully from relative path. My lib is linked statically to main app, so it needed initialization with `Q_INIT_RESOURCE`

Additional spotted issues:

1. [Q_INIT_RESOURCE cannot be in namespace](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40119).
2. Path must be in `:/fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf` form, NOT in `qrc:/fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf`.